# React render is choking on nested object in property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this react component. It is passed a prop called data.

data is an object like

```
{ 
  "title" : "some title",
  "meta" : { "name": "frank", 
             "last": "lee" 
           }
}



export default class Details extends React.Component {

  constructor () {
    super()

    this.state = {
      data: []
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.data.title}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

This renders fine. Howerever when I try to reference the nested object included in this prop the whole prop becomes "undefined" and I cannot reference anything.

Full Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

This breaks:

```
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.data.title}</h1>
        <p>{this.props.data.meta.name}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

This breaks:

```
  render () {

    var name = this.props.data.meta.name

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.data.title}</h1>
        <p>{name}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

everything breaks. I'm sure it's something small that i'm overlooking and some extra eyes might help me out here.

edit:

This is the Component calling Details.jsx

```
import Details from './Details.jsx'

export default class DetailsWrap extends React.Component{
  constructor () {
    super()

    this.state = {
      data: []
    }
  }

  loadData = (id) => {
    apipromise.getDetails(id)
    .success((response) => {

      this.setState({
        data: response
      })

    })
    .fail((response) => {

    });
  }

  componentDidMount () {

    this.loadData(this.props.id)
  }

  render () {

    return (
        <Details data={this.state.data}/>
    )
  }

};
```

Comment: Can you share the code **from where you pass the prop**

Comment: yes, one moment

Comment: try `componentWillMount` instead of `componentDidMount`

Comment: It just gives me a new error following the first one:

    react-with-addons.min.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks as though `data` is not necessarily set before `render` fires. Since you set an initial (empty) `data` property, when you call `this.props.data.title` on the initial render, the value is *null* but it doesn't blow up because the object is sufficiently shallow. However, calling `name` on an empty `meta` property blows up, because `meta` doesn't exist.

You've set loadData to use a promise, but that promise doesn't prevent the initial render of the component, where the error is occurring. Your best bet is to either render nothing until `this.props.data.meta` has a value, or else hedge your `name` variable, eg.

```
const name = this.props.data.meta && this.props.data.meta.name;
```

This will likely still flash `undefined`, though it won't blow up.

Comment: Well you've got me in the right direction. Adding that line preventing the render from crapping out and the name shows up. I must be structuring this wrong somehow though. I'm going to be passing some more complex data to that component (such as a list that will need to map node creations), and while your solution works it doesn't feel right. At least for more complex structures. if that makes sense.

Comment: @DigitalDisaster You'll have to handle it, or you can pass a `default data object`

Comment: Fair enough. I'll take this and run with it. Thank you all so much.

Comment: Incidentally, optional chaining is in [stage1](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining), and you can use it now with [babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-optional-chaining)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very wild guess.. but what about a coma after the title value?

Comment: sorry, that was just a type in the example. if I console.log(this.props.data) without anything in render the whole object is presented properly in the console.

Comment: try componentWillUpdate instead

Comment: This was mentioned above, changing that gives me the old error plus a new one/

`react-with-addons.min.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null `

I think maybe I should start from scratch or use one of my working components as a template