# React - TypeError: Cannot read property 'smallThumbnail' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to fetch some data from Google Books APIs. Now, I'm creating the page of the book selected by users where you found more informations about it. But, I stopped when I tried to get the image of the book, it seems that `useState` cannot access to the object of it.

```js
function Book (match) {
  

    useEffect(() => {
        getBook()
    },[])

    const [items, setItems] = useState([])


    const getBook = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${match.match.params.id}&key=MyKey`)
        const data = await response.json()
        setItems(data.items[0].volumeInfo)
        console.log(data.items[0].volumeInfo)
        
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>{items.title}</h1>
            <h1>{items.authors}</h1>
            <img src={items.imageLinks.smallThumbnail} alt="img"/>
        </div>
    )}

export default Book
```

[image]

Comment: I solved putting `imageLinks` like an object into `useState`

Comment: That is one way . Other is way how I updated in the answer , along with the link to understand the issue better

Answer (score 0):

SInce items is an array and not object . Update your code from

```
 <img src={items.imageLinks.smallThumbnail} alt="img"/>
```

to

```
 <img src={items.imageLinks&&items.imageLinks.smallThumbnail} alt="img"/>
```

You can read about this issue more here
[React render is choking on nested object in property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39615753/react-render-is-choking-on-nested-object-in-property)

Comment: Frank I update the code and also added the link where you can read about the issue .

Answer (score 0):

When you rendering the component first time , it don't have state variable "items" set yet.
Perform conditional rendering of your component.

```
if (isEmpty(items)) return 'Loading ...'
return(
        <div>
            <h1>{items.title}</h1>
            <h1>{items.authors}</h1>
            <img src={items.imageLinks.smallThumbnail} alt="img"/>
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: That's ok. But it isn't empty in my case. I can see the image from its data json.